# adding extra permission checks to django-rest-framework browsable api login

Tags: python, django, rest, permissions, django-rest-framework

Currently I've extended the standard Django user class by linking it to a profile class.  The profile model is partially used for account activation through email, and includes an account_activated boolean.  I'd like to require that accounts be activated in order to login in any way, including using the login button that is added to the django rest framework browsable api by adding

```
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',
                           namespace='rest_framework')),
```

from the tutorial here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/

to the project urls.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a classical example where permissions work fine. What you need to do:

1. Create a permission class that will check for a user if her account
   is activated. For more see [drf documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/);
2. Add your new permission class to the set of default permissions in settings.py in drf settings:

**settings.py**

```
  REST_FRAMEWORK = { 
            ...,
            'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [ 
                ..., 
                'your.permission.class', 
                ..., 
            ],
             ... 
        }
```